# "Insufficient Privileges error" happens when opening Subscriber Organization Detail in LMO

Tags: subscriber, lmo

In two cases I see  "Insufficient Privileges error" error  when opening Subscriber Organization Detail in LMO.

1. When I am logged into subscriber organization by username and password (where my package is installed)
2. Then I open subscriber organization detail from LMO.
3. When I go back to my subscriber organization and perform any action, "Insufficient Privileges error" happens.

Also,

4. When the package is installed into LMO, and I open LMO subscriber organization detail and then try to return and open any other tab, the same error happens.

What might be the possible reason for such behavior? Is there any workaround other than relogin to the target org?

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a case on 9/29/2021 1:26 PM regarding various issues in the Licensing Management Application, one of the question was about this  "Insufficient Privileges error" problem.

Support representative opened another sub-case related to this problem on 10/22/2021 3:50 PM

On 11/10/2021 11:01 AM, I received the following response from the higher level of support

> Installing a package on an LMO org and Accessing the same LMO org from
> the subscriber tab is not a correct use case. As both orgs have the
> same domains and when you access the org via subscriber a new session
> is generated and the old session becomes stale. When you log out from
> subscriber org main org session is logged out.

> You can check all the details on that org via direct login. Also, the
> same applies to the Subscriber org login i.e., a new session is
> generated when you log in and the old session becomes stale. If you
> want to access the previous session then you need to re-login.